# Dúvida sobre Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

Comecei a estudar *Java* e mexer no *Android Studio* recentemente. Estou tentando mexer no código (*open source*) abaixo para poder colocar um aplicativo na *PlayStore*.

https://github.com/sathishmscict/polar-dashboard

Porém, na hora de criar o *APK* a opção "*build generated signed apk*" não aparece dentro da aba *Build*. Alguém saberia o motivo?

Ao importar o arquivo para o *Android Studio* também me aparece este erro que eu não consigo solucionar:

> ```
> "Gradle 'polar-dashboard-master' project refresh failed" "Could not find com.afollestad:drag-select-recyclerview:0.4.0."
> ```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Ele não aparece ou aparece desabilitado? Você adicionou `com.afollestad:drag-select-recyclerview:0.4.0` no projeto?

Comment: A opção "build generated signed apk" não aparece. Quando abro o arquivo não existe essa opção dentro da aba Build.
Eu não adicionei "com.afollestad:drag-select-recyclerview:0.4.0" até porque não entendi o que seria essa mensagem.

Coloquei um print caso ajude em algo.

Comment: Adicione a biblioteca acima no seu *Gradle* `implementation com.afollestad:drag-select-recyclerview:0.4.0` e sincronize o projeto.

Comment: Desculpe eu tenho muito pouca experiência com o Android Studio e estou com um pouco de dificuldade de encontrar essa biblioteca, mas mesmo assim agradeço a ajuda.